# How to rewrite( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.Space ) =>Input.GetTouch

Tags: java, c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

how to `(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)` => `Input.GetTouch`

Originally my code was `(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)`
Now I want to change the software to use on Android phones
I heard that I want to use `Input.GetTouch`

How can I rewrite it `(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)`
to change into `Input.GetTouch`

Answer (score 0):

You would use e.g.

```
if((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
```

The last to be still able to debug it simply in the editor ;)

see

- [`Input.touchCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touchCount.html)
- [`Input.GetTouch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)
- [`Touch.phase`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html)